# How to typeset deep and multi-page enumerations nicely and quickly?

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem, horizontal-spacing

Consider a mathematical proof with a long a nested case distinction spanning multiple pages:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{enumitem}%\setlistdepth{6}%% do we need this?
\begin{document}
\setlist[description]{nosep,font=\normalfont,style=sameline}
\begin{description}
\item[Case \(i=0\).] 5 lines.
\item[Case \(i=1\).] 3 lines.
  \begin{description}
  \item[Case \(a0t0a1\).] 1 line
    \begin{description}
    \item[Case \ldots.] 6 lines
    \item[Case \ldots.]\strut
      \begin{description}
      \item[Case \ldots.] 9 lines
      \item[Case \ldots.] 11 lines
        \begin{description}
        \item [Case \ldots.] 6 lines
        \item [Case \ldots.] 7 lines
        \item [Case \ldots.] 5 lines
        \item [Case \ldots.] 6 lines
        \end{description}
      \end{description}
    \end{description}
  \item[Case \(a0n0a1\).] 2 lines
    \begin{description}
    \item[Case \ldots.] 4 lines
    \item[Case \ldots.] 3 lines
      \begin{description}
      \item[Case \ldots.] 3 lines
      \item[Case \ldots.] 5 lines
      \item[Case \ldots.] 3 lines
        \begin{description}
        \item[Case \ldots.] 4 lines
        \item[Case \ldots.] 5 lines
          \begin{description}
          \item[Case \ldots.] 5 lines
          \item[Case \ldots.] 6 lines
          \item[None of the two previous subcases.] 10 lines
          \end{description}
        \end{description}
      \end{description}
    \end{description}
  \end{description}
\item[Case \(2\le i \le n{-}1\).] 2 lines
  \begin{description}
  \item[Case \(c\neq 0\).] 1 line
    \begin{description}
    \item[Case \ldots.] 7 lines
    \item[Case \ldots.]\strut
      \begin{description}
      \item[Case \ldots.] 2 lines
        \begin{description}
        \item[Case \ldots.] 6 lines
        \item[Case \ldots.]\strut
          \begin{description}
          \item[Case \ldots.] 7 lines
          \item[Case \ldots.] 15 lines
          \end{description}
        \end{description}
      \item[Case \ldots.] 7 lines
      \end{description}
    \end{description}
  \item[Case \(c=0\).] 6 lines
  \end{description}
\item[Case \(i=n\).] 2 lines
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Running `pdflatex` on it yields

[image: output with non-enumerated case items]

As our non-minimal example spans multiple pages (and some lines are higher than usual due to matrices and case splits inside maths), indentation doesn't help the reader as much as if the whole contents were on one page.

Our current solution is to enumerate the cases hierarchically:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{enumitem}
% \setlistdepth{6}%% do we need this?
\newlength{\origlabelsep}
\setlength{\origlabelsep}{\labelsep}
\newlist{deepEnum}{enumerate}{6}
\setlist[deepEnum,1]{nosep,font=\normalfont,style=sameline,label*=Case \arabic*,labelsep=0pt}
\setlist[deepEnum,2,3,4,5,6]{nosep,font=\normalfont,style=sameline,label*=.\arabic*}
\newcommand{\deepEnumItem}[1]{\item: #1.}
\newcommand{\deepEnumItemAndSkip}[1]{\item: #1.\hskip\origlabelsep\relax}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\leftmarginv}{16pt}%% any non ad-hoc number?
\setlength{\leftmarginvi}{15pt}%% any non ad-hoc number?
\begin{deepEnum}
  \deepEnumItemAndSkip{\(i=0\)}5 lines.
  \deepEnumItemAndSkip{\(i=1\)}3 lines.
  \begin{deepEnum}
    \deepEnumItemAndSkip{\(a0t0a1\)}1 line
    \begin{deepEnum}
      \deepEnumItemAndSkip{\ldots}6 lines
      \deepEnumItem{\ldots}\strut
      \begin{deepEnum}
        \deepEnumItemAndSkip{\ldots}9 lines
        \deepEnumItemAndSkip{\ldots}11 lines
        \begin{deepEnum}
          \deepEnumItemAndSkip{\ldots}6 lines
          \deepEnumItemAndSkip{\ldots}7 lines
          \deepEnumItemAndSkip{\ldots}5 lines
          \deepEnumItemAndSkip{\ldots}6 lines
        \end{deepEnum}
      \end{deepEnum}
    \end{deepEnum}
    \deepEnumItemAndSkip{\(a0n0a1\)}2 lines
    \begin{deepEnum}
      \deepEnumItemAndSkip{\ldots}4 lines
      \deepEnumItemAndSkip{\ldots}3 lines
      \begin{deepEnum}
        \deepEnumItemAndSkip{\ldots}3 lines
        \deepEnumItemAndSkip{\ldots}5 lines
        \deepEnumItemAndSkip{\ldots}3 lines
        \begin{deepEnum}
          \deepEnumItemAndSkip{\ldots}4 lines
          \deepEnumItemAndSkip{\ldots}5 lines
          \begin{deepEnum}
            \deepEnumItemAndSkip{\ldots}5 lines
            \deepEnumItemAndSkip{\ldots}6 lines
            \deepEnumItemAndSkip{None of the two previous subcases}10 lines
          \end{deepEnum}
        \end{deepEnum}
      \end{deepEnum}
    \end{deepEnum}
  \end{deepEnum}
  \deepEnumItemAndSkip{\(2\le i \le n{-}1\)}2 lines
  \begin{deepEnum}
    \deepEnumItemAndSkip{\(c\neq 0\)}1 line
    \begin{deepEnum}
      \deepEnumItemAndSkip{\ldots}7 lines
    \item: \ldots.\strut
      \begin{deepEnum}
        \deepEnumItemAndSkip{\ldots}2 lines
        \begin{deepEnum}
          \deepEnumItemAndSkip{\ldots}6 lines
          \deepEnumItemAndSkip{\ldots}\strut
          \begin{deepEnum}
            \deepEnumItemAndSkip{\ldots}7 lines
            \deepEnumItemAndSkip{\ldots}15 lines
          \end{deepEnum}
        \end{deepEnum}
        \deepEnumItemAndSkip{\ldots}7 lines
      \end{deepEnum}
    \end{deepEnum}
    \deepEnumItemAndSkip{\(c=0\)}6 lines
  \end{deepEnum}
  \deepEnumItemAndSkip{\(i=n\)}2 lines
\end{deepEnum}
\end{document}
```

Running `pdflatex` on it yields

[image: output with enumerated case items]

1. Any better graphical way to represent the case distinction?
2. Do we need `\setlistdepth{6}`? Though I see it in my non-minimal code (so probably it was useful once), I fail to see how it helps here now. Adding this command yields the same PDF file up to meta data.
3. In our solution, adding a skip after the full stops terminating the semantic item names is cumbersome, requiring separate macros depending on whether visible text follows on the same line or the rest of the line is empty. Moreover, `\deepEnumItemAndSkip{\ldots}stuff` and `\deepEnumItemAndSkip{\ldots} stuff` produce different results (whereas `\item stuff` and `\item  stuff` produce the same result). Any better way to automate the conditional addition of this horizontal space?
4. In our solution, the left margin for depth 5 was too close to the left margin for depth 4, and the left margin for depth 6 was too close to the left margin for depth 5. We wanted to ensure that the increase of the left margin from depth  to depth +1 is always visible enough, being ideally, e.g., at least 1 en, (⩾1). Following [John's comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/707396/how-to-automate-horizontal-label-spacing-for-deep-multipage-enumerations-with-en#comment1758754_707396) (thx!), we set `\leftmarginv` and `\leftmarginvi`, and chose 16 pt and 15 pt, respectively. However, these values are ad hoc. How to get more systematic values for the increase, e.g., *max{original increase, 1 en}* or *if original increase <= 1 en then 1 en else (original increase + 1 en)/2 fi*?
5. Typesetting long and deep case splits should be a standard task. Above, we seem to be reinventing the wheel. Has there been another, easier solution in the LaTeX world already?

Comment: You are nesting at least 5 levels, and deepEnum has 6 levels, so I would include `\setlistdepth{6}` (default is 4).  You might find the outlines package interesting.  The indentations are set by `\leftmargini`, `\leftmarginii`, etc.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thank you! For our MWEs, comparing the PDF files resulting from compilation with and without `\setlistdepth{6}` yields differences only in the meta data. The documentation of the outlines package says that it has a nesting limit of 4. Saying `\setlength{\leftmarginv}{16pt}\setlength{\leftmarginvi}{15pt}` worked.